# Is there any usage for nested try if without catch?

Tags: java, oop, exception, io, try-catch

Came across the below code from a Java book

```java
public void writeFile(String fileName, String content){
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try {
        try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
          output.println(content);
          output.println();
          output.println("End of writing");
        }
        System.out.println("File been written successfully");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Nothing is wrong with the above code, I simply couldn't see the point of having a nested `try` that doesn't define an inner catch block. Or is there any purpose of doing so in which I've missed it?

**Revised code:**

```java
public void writeFile(String fileName, String content){
    File file = new File(fileName);

    try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        output.println(content);
        output.println();
        output.println("End of writing");
        System.out.println("File been written successfully");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inner try will automatically close the resource of PrintWriter, from jdk 9 you can have try without finally or catch

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @Deadpool: In other words, before jdk 9, developer will usually have to manually close it in `finally` block?

Comment: Yes exactly @Isaac and basically you do all these in one try catch, don't need of inner

Comment: I don't think it has much sense you can use an inner catch.

Comment: Move last sysout into try and log error in inner catch would be better code according to me

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Could you be kind enough to share some code snippet in Answer below? Reason is im a total newbie in Java and couldn't understand your statement

Comment: @Isaac on mobile phone, having a cappuccino so I cant right no, but just try it (see previous comment on how to it)

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Do you mind to have a look on the revised code to see if it's what you mean?

Comment: Exactly but answer instead :)

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Thank you very much on not just providing correct answer but also guiding to write a cleaner and better code. Have a great day!

Comment: Just to clarify:  try-with-resources statements are available starting with Java 7.

Comment: @Isaac as far as code smell the revised code is better because it reduce [cyclomatic complexity](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.metrics.CyclomaticComplexityCheck?layout=false) also making a method catching an error like that is crappy (at least you should return true/false), how does caller know if it did write the file or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner try is a try-with-resources:

```
try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file)))
```

it means, that it manages the resource - `PrintWriter` - opens it and closes it after every statement in this try is conducted. The outer try is used to catch the error.

Your revised code what Petter Friberg proposed, is equivalent.

Comment: You could use an inner catch instead, I dont see much purpose

Comment: @PetterFriberg you mean `finally`?

Comment: No just an inner catch, same code without outer try catch

Comment: "is equivalent" not quite. In the original code, the successful message is written after the print writer is closed. In the revised code, it is written before closing. An exception could occur in closing.

Comment: @AndyTurner the PrintWriter since java 7 will not throw IOException on close() AFIK https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close(), hence it would not be caught anyway

Comment: @PetterFriberg what about when closing the `FileWriter`?

Comment: @AndyTurner AFIK it's wrapped, open source code gives this http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/io/PrintWriter-source.html see line 255. Overall I agree there is this slight difference a Runtime Exception could happen during close, the method would throw error, but the line would never be printed (the code snippet does not however seem to want contemplate this, hence this is not the objective with the code), **In general** you should not *normally* program for this, hence in overall terms the second solution is better since it avoids cyclomatic complexity.